# C++ getline in for loop

Tags: c++

I learn to program in `c++` with previous experience with `python` and `R`. Id say I understand for loops well, but now I found out that I do not know nothig about them. Here is piece of code.

```
for (int i = 0; i != 1; ){
    string name;
    getline(infile, name);
    if (name == end_input){
        i = 1;
    }
    else{
        names.push_back(name);
    }
}
```

Whole program should (and do) read names (`name`) from file `infile` and store them into `names` string. Than I want them to store in another file. When I look on the code, I would thing `c++` do following instructions:

create integer `i` and set it to 0

create string name

read the line from `infile` and store this line into `names` string vector.

this will repeat unless `name == end_input`

From this I would say that `c++` will store first line in `input` file again and again because I didnt tell him to jump to next line after `getline` the first line. But program reads all names from that file, line by line as expected by author. How is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Because `getline` modifies the position of the file to the end of the line that it read so you don't need `getline` `set_file_position_to_next_line` pairs everywhere.

Comment: instead of that for loop you can try to use a while(i!=1) and assign i to zero above it.

Comment: Also since this is apparently not your code, don't look at it too closely. It is not good code and you should not try to learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

`getline` automatically moves to the next line after reading a line.

Also a `do while` loop might serve your purposes better here.

Answer (score 1):

When an inbuilt function does not behave as you expected, the logical next step should be to check the [Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/). If you do, you will see the following:

> Extracts characters from is and stores them into str until the delimitation character delim is found (or the newline character, '\n', for (2)).
>
> The extraction also stops if the end of file is reached in is or if some other error occurs during the input operation.
>
> If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded (i.e. it is not stored and the next input operation will begin after it).

Which answers your Question.

Comment: I tried to read some tutorials but I didnt look at official dcumentation indeed. Ill do it next time. Thx a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, reading that documentation through the eyes of a beginner, it is not obvious that the stream position indicator is moved with every getline()